# Connect search bar and search results components to global state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to ReactJS and I recently came up with this redux date store that react uses mostly.
I am trying to have a good grasp on it.

Just for the understanding purpose, I have an Array of Objects stored in the store in a static manner for now.

like this:

```
const initialState = {


jsonData: [
    {
     "id": "1",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "PM2.5",
     "pollutant_min": "62",
     "pollutant_max": "278",
     "pollutant_avg": "139",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "2",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "PM10",
     "pollutant_min": "74",
     "pollutant_max": "136",
     "pollutant_avg": "104",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "149",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Delhi",
     "city": "Delhi",
     "station": "Lodhi Road, Delhi - IMD",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "NO2",
     "pollutant_min": "NA",
     "pollutant_max": "NA",
     "pollutant_avg": "NA",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "150",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Delhi",
     "city": "Delhi",
     "station": "Lodhi Road, Delhi - IMD",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "CO",
     "pollutant_min": "34",
     "pollutant_max": "117",
     "pollutant_avg": "57",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
]
```

I am trying to create an action like this:

```
  { 
    type: "SEARCH",
    payload: {
      pattern: 'Mah'
    } 
  }
```

and I am dispatching this action. and trying to filter the store based on the pattern.
I am taking a pattern and converting it as a RegExp. and using the test function to filter the data.

But somehow, It's not working the data is not getting filtered using RegExp.
I am getting the same state even after filtering the data.
I am not able to understand whats the problem is:

Here is the full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

const initialState = {
  jsonData: [
    {
     "id": "1",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "PM2.5",
     "pollutant_min": "62",
     "pollutant_max": "278",
     "pollutant_avg": "139",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "2",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "PM10",
     "pollutant_min": "74",
     "pollutant_max": "136",
     "pollutant_avg": "104",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "149",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Delhi",
     "city": "Delhi",
     "station": "Lodhi Road, Delhi - IMD",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "NO2",
     "pollutant_min": "NA",
     "pollutant_max": "NA",
     "pollutant_avg": "NA",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "150",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Delhi",
     "city": "Delhi",
     "station": "Lodhi Road, Delhi - IMD",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "CO",
     "pollutant_min": "34",
     "pollutant_max": "117",
     "pollutant_avg": "57",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },

  ]
};

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('reducer', state, action); 

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SEARCH':      
      const updatedPattern =  new RegExp(action.payload.pattern)
      return {
        jsonData: initialState.jsonData.filter(item => updatedPattern.test(item.state))
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function getState() {
  console.log(initialState.jsonData);
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

store.dispatch(
  { 
    type: "SEARCH",
    payload: {
      pattern: 'And'
    } 
  }
);
getState();



ReactDOM.render(  
  <Provider store={store}>    
    <App />
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You're filtering `initialState` instead of `state`

Comment: You are successfully updating the store, but `console.log(initialState.jsonData)` confuses you, you should log the new state there by using `store.getState()`.

Comment: try mutating state like this   `return {...state,jsonData:initialState.jsonData.filter(item => updatedPattern.test(item.state)) };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. You should change your store display function which always record to origin data

Maybe you can change this to see store change:

```
function getState() {
  console.log(store.getState());
}
```

Just `console.log(initialState.jsonData);` always show the origin data.

#### 2. `reducer` function always need to change the current state

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('reducer', state, action); 

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SEARCH':      
      const updatedPattern =  new RegExp(action.payload.pattern)
      return {
        jsonData: state.jsonData.filter(item => updatedPattern.test(item.state))
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The key change is after: `jsonData: state.jsonData.filter(item => updatedPattern.test(item.state))`

#### 3. Maybe you can use `store.subscribe(handleChange)` to get store change

```
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(getState)
```

use the `store.subscribe` to auto get state change action like `react-redux` does.

Comment: `react-redux` must be `redux`

Comment: Here in the last sentence `use the store.subscribe to auto get state change action like react-redux does`. Or maybe I didn't understand what you meant:(

Comment: @SuleymanSah Ehh... I guess asker create function `getState()` and execute it wanna get the newest store after dispatch action.So I suggest asker to use `store.subscribe` to auto get newest store after change.

Comment: @SuleymanSah In `react-redux` `Provider` Component, need to use `store.subscribe` to get newest store. Ehh... could you understand me?

Comment: @SuleymanSah maybe I think too much but cannot  express well. The main is: **I guess asker wanna get change of store**, so I recommend him to use `store.subscribe`

Comment: This answer shouldn't be neither upvoted, nor accepted as it does **NOT** provide exact solution to OP's problem. Moreover, it promotes the pattern that is not recommended (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59718562/11299053) for details)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Ehh... your answer first advice I approve. search something should always search the origin array. And search array maybe not place in redux.

Comment: @tomioion : the most important is not even the first suggestion, but the last one - proposed in your answer `subscribe ... store.dispatch()` to dispatch actions is **anti-pattern**

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov You misunderstand my viewpoint.**I guess asker wanna get change of store**, so I recommend him to use `store.subscribe` not advice to use `store.dispatch` to create action.

Comment: @tomioion : `subscribe()` method is used to listen for the actions being dispatched and trigger custom callback - it is neither the way of getting variables from global state, nor the way of dispatching actions (you would use `connect()` or `useSelector()`, `useDispatch()` for that purpose). This is, basically, why I said there's no actual answer in your post.

Answer (score 2):

### Since both OP's approach and accepted answer **have several critical flaws** let me share my suggestions:

- you don't want to replace source array within your current state with its filtered copy - if you typed `Mah` within your search bar and just one second later decided to search for `elh` you may get an empty search results if your previously filtered array didn't contain matches (while original one did);
- using RegExp `test()` for basic case-insensitive partial match is an absolute overkill, there's a much less expensive option, based on [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) together with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/some) if required (you may refer live-snippet on the bottom for example);
- both earlier posted solutions suggest using `subscribe... store.dispatch()` pattern to access globally stored state variables, which [is not recommended](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#can-i-call-storedispatch)

If you really need to keep your search results stored within global state and you want to obtain those through dispatching corresponding action (e.g. `SEARCH`) and accessing global `searchResults` within arbitrary component [`connect()`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect) method, combined with `mapDispatchToProps()` and `mapStateToProps()`, respectively, should be used.

You may find the live-demo below:

```js
//dependencies
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux
      
//search action, initial state, reducer, store
const SEARCH = 'SEARCH',
      initialState = {jsonData:[{"id":"1","country":"India","state":"Andhra_Pradesh","city":"Amaravati","station":"Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB","last_update":"18-12-2019 09:00:00","pollutant_id":"PM2.5","pollutant_min":"62","pollutant_max":"278","pollutant_avg":"139","pollutant_unit":"NA"},{"id":"2","country":"India","state":"Andhra_Pradesh","city":"Amaravati","station":"Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB","last_update":"18-12-2019 09:00:00","pollutant_id":"PM10","pollutant_min":"74","pollutant_max":"136","pollutant_avg":"104","pollutant_unit":"NA"},{"id":"149","country":"India","state":"Delhi","city":"Delhi","station":"Lodhi Road, Delhi - IMD","last_update":"18-12-2019 09:00:00","pollutant_id":"NO2","pollutant_min":"NA","pollutant_max":"NA","pollutant_avg":"NA","pollutant_unit":"NA"},{"id":"150","country":"India","state":"Delhi","city":"Delhi","station":"Lodhi Road, Delhi - IMD","last_update":"18-12-2019 09:00:00","pollutant_id":"CO","pollutant_min":"34","pollutant_max":"117","pollutant_avg":"57","pollutant_unit":"NA"}], searchResult:[]},
      appReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case SEARCH : {
            const {jsonData} = state,
                  {searchedString} = action,
                  searchResult = searchedString.length ? 
                    jsonData.filter(item => 
                      Object.values(item).some(val =>
                        val
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .includes(searchedString.toLowerCase()))) :
                    []
            return {...state, searchResult}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)

//searchbar ui component
const SearchBar = ({searchResults}) => (
  <input onKeyUp={e => searchResults(e.target.value)} />
)

//connect searchbar component's searchResult prop to dispatching SEARCH action
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        searchResults: val => dispatch({type: SEARCH, searchedString: val})
      }),
      SearchBarContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar)
      
//search results ui component
const SearchResults = ({results}) => (
  <div>
    {results.map(item => <div>{JSON.stringify(item)}</div>)}
  </div>
)
//connect global state searchResult to component's results
const mapStateToProps = ({searchResult:results}) => ({results}),
      SearchResultsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchResults)
      
//global Povider wrapper
render (
  <Provider {...{store}}>
    <SearchBarContainer />
    <SearchResultsContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.3/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```