# Redux - Cannot find directory to call dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am really having hard times dealing with Redux. I am referring to this [link](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/). Some how i made my project redux part modular by following the steps given on the link.

Now i am stuck. I cannot find a suitable directory to use the dispatch & also check whether my action has worked correctly or not.

This is how my directory looks like as of now:

[image: project structure]

I tried implementing redux but not able to work my way out.

I have an array of objects. and I need to find a suitable object based on the key.
This is how the Array of Objects looks like

```
[
    {
     "id": "1",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "PM2.5",
     "pollutant_min": "62",
     "pollutant_max": "278",
     "pollutant_avg": "139",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "2",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "PM10",
     "pollutant_min": "74",
     "pollutant_max": "136",
     "pollutant_avg": "104",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "3",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "NO2",
     "pollutant_min": "15",
     "pollutant_max": "38",
     "pollutant_avg": "22",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "4",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "NH3",
     "pollutant_min": "4",
     "pollutant_max": "6",
     "pollutant_avg": "5",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "5",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "SO2",
     "pollutant_min": "2",
     "pollutant_max": "34",
     "pollutant_avg": "16",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "6",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "CO",
     "pollutant_min": "20",
     "pollutant_max": "63",
     "pollutant_avg": "33",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   }
]
```

***state*** is the key with which i need to search the pattern & return the relevant result.

This is how other files look like

actions/action-types.js:

```
export const SEARCH = "SEARCH_STATE";
```

actions/index.js

```
import { SEARCH } from "./action-types";


export function search(payload) {
    return { type: SEARCH, payload }
};
```

reducers/index.js

```
import {SEARCH } from "../actions/action-types";
const initialState = {
  jsonData: [
    {
     "id": "1",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "PM2.5",
     "pollutant_min": "62",
     "pollutant_max": "278",
     "pollutant_avg": "139",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "2",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "PM10",
     "pollutant_min": "74",
     "pollutant_max": "136",
     "pollutant_avg": "104",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "3",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "NO2",
     "pollutant_min": "15",
     "pollutant_max": "38",
     "pollutant_avg": "22",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "4",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "NH3",
     "pollutant_min": "4",
     "pollutant_max": "6",
     "pollutant_avg": "5",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "5",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "SO2",
     "pollutant_min": "2",
     "pollutant_max": "34",
     "pollutant_avg": "16",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "6",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "CO",
     "pollutant_min": "20",
     "pollutant_max": "63",
     "pollutant_avg": "33",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   },
   {
     "id": "7",
     "country": "India",
     "state": "Andhra_Pradesh",
     "city": "Amaravati",
     "station": "Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB",
     "last_update": "18-12-2019 09:00:00",
     "pollutant_id": "OZONE",
     "pollutant_min": "31",
     "pollutant_max": "77",
     "pollutant_avg": "66",
     "pollutant_unit": "NA"
   }
];




function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === SEARCH) {
      const pattern = new RegExp('And');      
    return {
        jsonData: initialState.jsonData.filter((item) => pattern.test(item.state))
    }
  }
  return state;
}

function getState() {
    console.log(initialState.getState());
}
export default rootReducer;
```

store/index.js:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

import rootReducer from "../reducers/index.js";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);



export default store;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import store from './store/index';



ReactDOM.render(  
  <Provider store={store}>    
    <App />
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I want to use the SEARCH action to filter the data based on the pattern(which I would be fetching as an input from the user & filter the data based on the pattern).

I am stuck on how to dispatch the action & how would I be checking whether my action has worked correctly or not.

Please help me... stuck with it for quite a long time.
I am expecting working code corrections. Since I am totally a newbie in redux as of now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post what you have in `App.js`? Technically that's the place where you might want to use `connect`, `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. Thanks!

Comment: @abhigyannayak:  Just for the record, asking same question over and over again until someone suggests *magic line* to your codebase doesn't make much sense, especially, assuming you've accepted the answer and already supposed to have your problem solved. By the way, in the thread, I'm referring to, I've  [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59718562/11299053) fixes to implement the feature you've been after and supplied live-demo.

Comment: @yevgen apologies. I was not able to read your thread after finding the correct answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: @abhigyannayak: no worries, however that answer was not right - it ignores critical threats within your code and does not deliver **proper** solution (you may read through comments under that post), that's, basically, why you've faced that problem again.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know....That thread you pointed out worked for me! :D

Answer (score 0):

In your `App` component:

```js
import {search} from "../actions/index.js";

class App extends React.Component{
/*
*  your code
*
*/
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   jsonData: state.jsonData
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      search: event => dispatch(search(event.target.value))
   }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```